# Comando no chat para abrir nova pagina javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá pessoal estou fazendo um chat e gostaria que quando o usuario digitar **/regras** e pressionar enter ele abre uma nova aba com o endereço das regras alguem poderia me ajudar com o codigo?

```
 <textarea type="text" name="emsg" id="emsg" maxlength="40" rows="1" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem"></textarea>
```

Comment: Desculpa, não compreendi. Poderia descrever mai o que você pretende fazer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, use a função do jquery `keypress` keycode = 13 para o enter.
A função `.slice(-8)` vai recuperar os últimos 8 carácteres digitados para a verificação "/regras"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#emsg").keypress(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if(key == 13) {
            console.log($("#emsg").val().slice(-8));
            if ($("#emsg").val().slice(-8) == "/regras") {
                window.open('www.google.com.br', '_blank');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <textarea id="emsg"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Lembre-se que ao usar o jquery você deve colocar seus métodos dentro de `$( document ).ready(function() {});`

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: Por acaso você sabe como eu troco meu textarea por um input e que ele não dê refresh no titulo/link do site?

Comment: Pode ser trocado facilmente por um input type=text mantendo a mesma id. Já o refresh não te compreendi...

Comment: é que estou usando um chat e ao inves de input estou usando textarea e gostaria de mudar, porém quando coloco input ele meio que da "refresh" no link do site, ficando com o id do input e =, ex: site.com/loja?emsg= eu queria que ele não ficasse assim =/

Comment: Isso acontece quando você digita no input? se sim provavelmente algum outro script esta fazendo este comportamento indesejado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar dessa forma, ao digitar `/regras` automaticamente vai abrir uma nova aba

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
        var emsg = $("#emsg").val();

        $("#emsg").focusout( function(){
             if(emsg == "/regras") {
                  window.open('www.google.com.br', '_blank');
             }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Testei aqui e só abre a aba nova se eu digitar /regras no text area e clicar fora, gostaria que ao apertar enter com o /regras no text area ele abriria a pagina desejada =/

Comment: conseguir configurar de um jeito aqui porém depois que digito /regras e dou enter ele abre a nova pagina porém qualquer letra que eu colocar no textarea ele vai me abrir uma nova pagina... =/